# Gluon, Android 10 Black screen issue

Tags: android, android-10.0, gluon-mobile

Code is working fine for Android 8 and 9, this issue only in Android 10. We can run in Android 10 by using the command `adb shell settings put global hidden_api_policy  1`. But this is again only device or Emulator specific.  Is there any general solution to fix this issue for Android 10.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher$1.run(DalvikLauncher.java:188)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$138(LauncherImpl.java:182)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$1(Unknown Source:8)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source:13)
W/System.err:   ... 1 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getLogger(Ljava/lang/String;)Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; in class Lsun/util/logging/PlatformLogger; or its super classes (declaration of 'sun.util.logging.PlatformLogger' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.util.Logging.getCSSLogger(Logging.java:98)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.css.parser.CSSParser.<clinit>(CSSParser.java:164)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.loadStylesheetUnPrivileged(StyleManager.java:1079)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.loadStylesheet(StyleManager.java:910)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager._addUserAgentStylesheet(StyleManager.java:1263)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager.setUserAgentStylesheets(StyleManager.java:1204)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$_setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet$165(PlatformImpl.java:698)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$13(Unknown Source:2)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$14.run(Unknown Source:4)
W/System.err:     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:43)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl._setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:697)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:548)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.setDefaultPlatformUserAgentStylesheet(PlatformImpl.java:512)
W/System.err:     at javafx.scene.control.Control.<clinit>(Control.java:86)
W/System.err:     at com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication.start(SourceFile:202)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$145(LauncherImpl.java:863)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$8(Unknown Source:4)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source:7)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$158(PlatformImpl.java:326)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$6(Unknown Source:4)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source:7)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$156(PlatformImpl.java:295)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(Unknown Source:2)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source:4)
W/System.err:     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:59)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$157(PlatformImpl.java:294)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$5(Unknown Source:4)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$6.run(Unknown Source:7)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:93)
W/System.err:     at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:52)
```

Below is the gradle file code of application, have added the dependency and configuration and per document.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.12'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'



repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
    }
}

mainClassName = 'com.gluonapplication.Sample'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
}

jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.8.0'
        // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    android {

        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
        forceLinkClasses = [
                'com.gluonhq.**.*',
                'javax.annotations.**.*',
                'javax.inject.**.*',
                'javax.json.**.*',
                'org.glassfish.json.**.*'
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Plugin `jfxmobile` is EOL. Latest version is 1.3.18 though, so you should update it, o better migrate your app to Java/FX 11+ with Client [plugin](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#_the_gluon_client_plugin_for_maven). As for a fix, this [commit](https://github.com/devoxx/MyDevoxxGluon/commit/a960b810e5688bd21d338cb47cf411c570078f73) is a workaround, that can be applied per app basis.

Comment: @JoséPereda  I just tried the workaround solution, it's giving the error   while running the code   ``` W/luonapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;->getRuntime()Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime; (greylist,core-platform-api, reflection, allowed)
W/luonapplicatio: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;->setHiddenApiExemptions([Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist,core-platform-api, reflection, denied)

Answer (score 1):

I used com.gluonhq.charm.down.common.PlatformFactory package insteed of com.gluonhq.attach.util.Platform for jfxmobile-plugin 1x versions. works fine